# How to set fixed rows and Columns in AdvStringGrid?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tms

Initially Columns and Rows Count are Zero, and i trying to set Fixed Columns and Rows are 1.

But Giving Error is

[image]

How to fix this?

TIA

Comment: It seems that you are introducing 1 fixed row in a grid without rows. Try to set Grid.RowCount := 1 before adding the fixed row

Answer (score 2):

The error message indicates that number of rows must be higher than the intended fixed rows. First increase `RowCount`, f.ex. to 2, then you can set `FixedRows` to 1. Same for columns.